# Why can't I accces my local server over cable but Wifi works

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, ssh, ethernet, subnet

I dont really know much about it, but asking since I would like to know why?, and if there is a simple way to solve the situation. I have a local Ubuntu server connected via wifi. I can SSH to my server and access any other service/address from any device that is connected to the same wifi network, but can't if i use my desktop pc that is connected via Ethernet Cable. If connect the server via Ethernet Cable i can SSH from any wifi device and desktop pc.

That may be because of my subnets? The LAN subnet is, for example: `198.190.0.0/26` and wifi is `198.190.10.0/26`. Dekstop is connected to the modem and wifi comes from a mesh that is connected via Ethernet cable to the modem.

How may I solve this, or how can I SSH into my server with my desktop pc?

Note: I can't keep my server connected via Ethernet Cable since it would need a long cable to its final location.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to put your wireless on the same subnet as the wired network?  That is the easiest and most reliable solution over the long haul. Get everything on one subnet

Comment: If it's a Windows PC, then there is an easy solution.  Is it ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. Idk if i can put my wireless subnet on the same of my wired one. Tbh, i cant really do much on my modem, it just a plain info page. @John

Comment: Yes, is a windows pc. @RohitGupta

Comment: @John Or you mean use static ip on 198.190.0.x (wired subnet) for the ubuntu server while the server being connected (via wifi) to mesh system that handles 198.190.10.x, isn't it?

Comment: It is easiest if your whole network is on one subnet.  Wireless can be put on the same subnet as the Wired network.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your problem is that you need to connect to two networks. This can be achieved on Windows as follows -

1. Click on the Network Icon on Taskbar
2. Click on **Change Adapter Options**
3. Click on the ethernet card (its the one that hasn't got Not Connected, TAP, VPN, TeamViewer etc beside it)
4. Click on <kbd>Properties</kbd> button
5. Select **Internet Protocol Version 4**
6. Click on <kbd>Properties</kbd> button
7. Click on <kbd>Advanced</kbd> button
8. Under **IP addresses**, Click on <kbd>Add</kbd> button
9. Enter  **198.190.10.xxx** and subnet of **255.255.255.0**
10. Click on <kbd>Add</kbd> button
11. Keep pressing <kbd>Ok</kbd> as you exit out.

I have assumed here that your desktop is connected to the Lan, so you need to put add your Wifi IP address.  Nominate an address for yourself, **xxx** can't be **0** and probably can't be **1** as your DHCP server is probably using that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my desktop is not connected to the wifi. That's why I have a different subnet, can I 'move' my desk subnet from 198.190.0.xxx to 198.190.1.xxx?

Comment: I have changed the answer accordingly.  If you just change the subnet on your laptop, then it will no longer connect to what it is connecting to now.  Either everything has to be on the same range, or you allow your laptop to be on two networks.

Comment: Thanks, but it just remove my ethernet acces. Think i just gonna buy a wifi 5 dongle.